# Same request - get error: 400 Bad Request - Advance REST Client

Tags: rest, http, postman

Execute http POST request by the Postman (**desktop** version):

http://127.0.0.1:8090/api/profiles/export

**Header:**

```
Host: 127.0.0.1:8090
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 282
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
X-XSRF-TOKEN: CfDJ8CQGvOgKAdr991T0W48TbmbJulHjCLSNl5Ufw9B-aa4W8FnpeleEvRxItMC3lj0KiyXTrhn9vOR3RCtTxSIpCh1d3JfjRIT2GRk3osT3e_7g
Authorization: gUqILBH5fUu+ZIU98Xq62g
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8090
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8090/folders/cpes/1189/profiles
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
Cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.vAmb-7is-9Q=CfDJ-N_Krwb3YlxI4utC_l6qsoVQQc8YY6DeFOfaTVHkx8bFMqDtjDRN0N1O3MmbfbRYSq72tic5B-MPpiybWUtaEbtaXIvHiBbRpOsYG5vj66tkYlrY-j6CA; XSRF-TOKEN=CfDJ8CQGvOgpT-VClVphMqoot5levDSTI5VFGbACv6z7_pXhiCrcdtKAdr991T0W48TbmbJulHjCLSNl5Ufw9B-aa4W8FnpeleEvRxItMC3lj0KiyXTrhn9vOR3RCtTxSIpCh1d3JfjRIT2GRk3osT3e_7g
```

**Payload**:

```
{"Interval":0,"Request":{"folderId":1189,"filter":"{}","visibleColumns":["profileType","name","description","managedGroups","parentFolder.name"],"visibleColumnsNames":["Profile Type","Name","Description","Assigned To (Managed Groups)","Parent"],"orders":"profileType:asc,name:asc"}}
```

Get success response:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "result": {
        "ftpAddress": "ftp://127.0.0.1/export/",
        "fileName": "admin_Profiles_20220728160913.csv"
    }
}
```

Nice. I can execute this request by POSTMAN many times with success response. OK.

Now I want to execute SAME POST request by **Advance REST Client** (Chrome extenstion).

But I get error:

```
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```